# Mi consulta a mi API se llama 4 veces, ReactJS, REDUX

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

Mi problema es el siguiente estoy haciendo una consulta de mi API para traer un array de objetos por medio de REDUX, ReactJS, todo esta bien, pero al momento de hacer el llamado se llama 4 veces, aclaro parace que en el network, refleja que se llama 4 veces, 3 de las cuales se muestran vacías [] y la ultima es la que esta llena pero no me sirve ya que esa cosnulta necesito guardarla en un State.

```
 useEffect( () => {

    const loadItems = () => dispatch( obtainItems() )
    loadItems()
   
},[])
```

Ahi hago el llamado con el dispacth de la funcion para que la cargue y con el useSelector guardo esos productos en una variable: items

```
const items = useSelector( state => state.items.items);
```

Pero como ven en la imagen me muestra los primeras consultas vacias y la ultima llena, obviamente no quiero eso solo se que llame una vez.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NOTA:** Estoy usando axios y async/await no se quizas eso tenga que ver.

Comment: Yo no veo 4 llamadas.. yo veo 4 salidas de informacion por consola, que no es lo mismo. para ver las llamadas, deberias ver la pestaña network... y deberiamos ver el codigo que llama a tu back, para ver si realmente hay un problema...

Comment: Buenas amigo gracias, tienes razon me equivoque tenia que mostrar el network para que veas que se hace 4 veces tienes razon, pero una pregunta esas salidas, porque se san asi si solo hago un llamado una ves ?

Comment: ni idea.. habria que ver que codigo muestra esas salidas...